# What's the difference between `*.framework`, `*.dylib` and `*.a` libs

Tags: ios, xcode, dylib, .a

I have a project, in the Framework, there have `*.framework`, `*.dylib`, `*.a` libs.

[image: 's the]

I want to know what's them? and the difference between them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Dynamic and static libraries

First of all, a library is a collection of resources and the code itself, compiled for one or more architectures.

**Static libraries (*.a):**

> In the case of `static libraries (*.a)`, the code that the app uses is
>   copied to the generated executable file by a static linker during
>   compilation time.

**Dynamic libraries (*.dylib):**

> `Dynamic libraries (*.dylib)` are different from static libraries in the
>   sense that they are linked with the app’s executable at runtime, but
>   not copied into it. As a result, the executable is smaller and,
>   because the code is loaded only when it is needed, the startup time is
>   typically faster.

## Dynamic and static frameworks:

> For frameworks, we first need to understand the [bundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle) concept (as a
>   framework is a specific kind of a bundle). A bundle is a file
>   directory with subdirectories inside. On iOS, bundles serve to
>   conveniently ship related files together in one package – **for**
>   **instance, images, nibs, or compiled code.** The system treats it as one
>   file and you can access bundle resources without knowing its internal
>   structure.
>
> The library may also have additional resources: **headers, localization**
>   **files, images, documentation, and examples of usage**. We can bundle all
>   of this together in one bundle – and the name of this is the framework.
>
> Static frameworks contain a static library packaged with its
>   resources. Dynamic frameworks contain the dynamic library with its
>   resources. In addition to that, dynamic frameworks may conveniently
>   include different versions of the same dynamic library in the same
>   framework!

## Other useful references:

[Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/static-and-dynamic-libraries-fe5d23daffe3)

[Runtastic](https://www.runtastic.com/blog/en/frameworks-ios/)

[Static library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library)

[Software framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework)

## Update:

Thanks for accepting my answer!

**Compiled for one or more architectures?**

> Every architecture requires a different binary, and when you build an
>   app Xcode will build the correct architecture for whatever you’re
>   currently working with. For instance, if you’ve asked it to run in the
>   simulator, then it’ll only build the i386 version (or x86_64 for
>   64-bit).
>
> This means that builds are as fast as they can be. When you archive an
>   app or build in release mode, then Xcode will build for all three ARM
>   architectures, thus allowing the app to run on most devices. What
>   about the other builds though?
>
> Naturally, when you build your framework, you’ll want developers to be
>   able to use it for all possible architectures, right? Of course you do
>   since that’ll mean you can earn the respect and admiration of your
>   peers.
>
> Therefore you need to make Xcode build for all five architectures.
>   This process creates a so-called fat binary, which contains a slice
>   for each of the architectures.

```
arm7: Used in the oldest iOS 7-supporting devices
arm7s: As used in iPhone 5 and 5C
arm64: For the 64-bit ARM processor in iPhone 5S
i386: For the 32-bit simulator
x86_64: Used in 64-bit simulator
```

[Raywenderlich: Multi-Architecture](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2430-how-to-create-a-framework-for-ios)

Comment: can you explain more about: `compiled for one or more architectures.`?